# Time range sql query

Tags: sql-server

Hello Every one I am little stuck in fetching records in SQL. I got a requirement that I have to fetch records din between of 5:00 PM to 8:00 AM. So far I did is given below.

```
select * from dlg_deal_transaction inner join dlg_deal on dlg_deal_transaction.deal_id = dlg_deal.id where Cast(dlg_deal_transaction.created_on as time) > '17:00:00.0000000' And
    Cast(dlg_deal_transaction.created_on as time) < '08:00:00.0000000'
```

Issue is that like I entered a record at 1:00 am and I want it to fetch in this time range as it is inserted in above time range so I want to fetch all the records which are inserted in table during 5:00 PM to next day 8:00 AM.

However I am still failed to achieve this. Will be very thankful if someone suggest me what should I do to achieve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wts the issue you have in the query or output? Or plz share the sample data and expected result.

Comment: I updated the question please check it :)

Comment: did u checked the answer by @Jeffrey Van Laethem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to change your AND to an OR. As-is, you're asking for every row where the time is > 5pm AND < 8am

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if the created date is of 01/01/2016 then it will go on to search records before 8 AM of the date and records after 5 PM of the date, you will never get your desired result of between. You can add one day to the created date and then your query might work.

```
select * from dlg_deal_transaction inner join dlg_deal on dlg_deal_transaction.deal_id = dlg_deal.id where Cast(dlg_deal_transaction.created_on as time) > '17:00:00.0000000' And
    Cast(DATEADD(day,1,dlg_deal_transaction.created_on) as time) < '08:00:00.0000000'
```